# How does Skimage's Hough_Ellipse work exactly?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, ellipse, hough-transform

I am currently working on a Bachelor Thesis to recognize & count eggs in a hen nest using Computer Vision methods. The eggs can be (partially) occluded by hens for a while and can be positioned in different rotations. My current ideas are using an Elliptic Hough Transform and an AI solution using YOLO - For tracking, I am currently researching :)

However, reading through [skimage's tutorial](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html#id2) about [Hough_Ellipse()](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html?highlight=hough_ellipse#skimage.transform.hough_ellipse) and trying to find resources, I am currently at a dead end which results in the following questions:

- What is an accumulator threshold value exactly?
- What is the accuracy and bin size on the minor axis?
- How do all these parameters work together to find ellipses along with min_size & max_size
  (min_size is minimal major axis length & max_size is maximal minor axis length)
- Isn't it that the major & minor axis can change?

For the transform, I currently am using Grayscaling -> Gaussian Blurring -> Canny Detection.
The result of the preprocessing looks like this at the moment:

[Preprocessed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxN6Y.png)

The preprocessing shows that there is - indeed - an ellipse. I am unsure whether FitEllipse() from OpenCV will end up helping me detecting Ellipses, especially when partially occluded by hens and having different possible rotations of an egg.
Furthermore, how do I figure out the individual parameters for Hough_Transform()?

PS: If anyone has better ideas aside from AI to test out, I'd be happy to try out more things :)

Comment: that is a very tiny image

Comment: Yeah, it's quite small, but it is definitely possible to make it bigger :)

Comment: afaik cv::fitEllipse works on point sets and does a least squares. pointless here because you have no "ellipse" points, just edge points. you're gonna need some type of hough transform or other approach. there are approaches that do hough for ellipses, and there are non-hough approaches

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yeah, I am currently struggling finding the proper parameters to find an egg through an Elliptic Hough Transform. The original image looks [like this](https://imgur.com/Ou8dzW3.png). You can guess that depending on position, rotation, shadowing etc., the detection becomes more complex over a video feed. Several eggs can be in the nest, even partially occluding them. Thus, setting parameters for one image in the feed using classic image preprocessing methods results in no correct detection. I am currently at a loss here aside from trying SVM w/ HOG and YOLO...

Comment: if the egg weren't occluded, I'd just say find edges/contours somehow, and evaluate the "roundness"... because eggs aren't ellipses from most perspectives. HoG might be promising. picture looks hazy, low contrast, aside from being tiny. I wonder, do eggs show better contrast under specific wavelengths, vs the nest?